# scriptProtect ColdFusion 9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I am trying to learn how to use `scriptProtect` but I was wondering if there is also something else that I need to do in order to secure my application as much as possible. Also, is scriptProtect acting as HTMLEditFormat or is it something completely separate?

And finally my application is under another application `ex: example.com/myapp/index.cfm` I suppose that I have to add the scriptProtect under the main `application.cfc` of `example.com` correct? And if so, should I expect errors due to this tag from the main app? Should I write a component that extends and the `application.cfc` and add the `scriptProtect` in there instead?

Comment: http://www.12robots.com/index.cfm/2010/3/1/A-warning-about-ColdFusions-scriptProtect

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the article. I think I will stick with HTMLEditiFormat() after all :)

Comment: or EncodeForXXXX() in CF10+ or CFBackPort : https://github.com/misterdai/cfbackport

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Henry has you on the right track. You definitely cannot solely rely on the `scriptProtect` functionality. However I think it is okay to use it in conjunction with other validation methods. And, for what its worth, there is a global setting in the ColdFusion administrator that enables `scriptProtect` for all applications running under that instance. It is named "Enable Global Script Protection" in the administrator and can be found under the Settings menu.

The `scriptProtect` setting is completely different than the `HTMLEditFormat` and `EncodeForXXXX()` functions.  I just wanted to point out that the `scriptProtect` and/or "Global Script Protection" rules can be customized. That setting works by applying a regular expression that is defined in the `cf_root/lib/neo-security.xml` file in the server configuration, or the `cf_root/WEB-INF/cfusion/lib/neo-security.xml` file in the JEE configuration to the variable value. You can customize the patterns that ColdFusion replaces by modifying the regular expression in the `CrossSiteScriptPatterns` variable.

The default regular expression is defined as:

```
<var name='CrossSiteScriptPatterns'>
    <struct type='coldfusion.server.ConfigMap'>
        <var name='&lt;\s*(object|embed|script|applet|meta)'>
            <string>&lt;InvalidTag</string>
        </var>
    </struct>
</var>
```

Which means, by default, the Global Script Protection mechanism is only looking for strings containing `<object` or `<embed` or `<script` or `<applet` or `<meta` in the `FORM`, `URL`, `CGI`, and `COOKIE` scopes and replacing them with `<InvalidTag`. You can enhance that regular expression to look for more cases and/or change the replacement string if you want.

See [Protecting variables from cross-site scripting attacks section on this page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7d69.html)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to write all these. I will start looking into security more seriously!